# Why my recycler view got so much separation between items?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I use recycler view before and i never have this problems. The principal difference between the other recycler views that i made is that i use SQLite for this one.
I want all the items appears one between other and without white spaces between them.

**LEADER BOARD ACTIVITY WHERE I INITIALIZE MY RECYCLER**

```
public class LeaderBoard extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerController mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leader_board);
        DaoSQLite manager=new DaoSQLite(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db=manager.getReadableDatabase();
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter=new RecyclerController(manager.getSortScores());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

**VIEW FOR RECYCLER**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/txtNameOption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbName"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbLevel2"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="154dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Level"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbScore"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="266dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Score"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:background="#604697"
        android:backgroundTint="#34BE3838"
        android:backgroundTintMode="src_in"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**THIS IS THE SQLite DAO**

```
package com.example.quizappjava.DataBase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.quizappjava.Beans.User;


public class DaoSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Game.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME_SCORES = "puntuaciones";
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();

    public DaoSQLite(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME_SCORES +" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT (15) NOT NULL,score INTEGER NOT NULL, level INTEGER NOT NULL)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public Cursor getSortScores(){
        return getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME_SCORES,null,null,null,null,null,"score");
    }
    public void insertNewScore(User user){
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME_SCORES,null,user.toContentValues());
    }

}
```

**RECYCLER CONTROLLER**

```
package com.example.quizappjava.JavaClasses;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.quizappjava.Beans.User;
import com.example.quizappjava.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerController extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerController.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<User> userArraList = new ArrayList<User>();



    public RecyclerController(Cursor queryRequest) {
        ParseData(queryRequest);
    }

    private void ParseData(Cursor queryRequest) {
        for (queryRequest.moveToFirst(); !queryRequest.isAfterLast(); queryRequest.moveToNext()) {
            userArraList.add(
                    new User(
                            queryRequest.getString(queryRequest.getColumnIndex("name")),
                            queryRequest.getInt(queryRequest.getColumnIndex("score")),
                            queryRequest.getInt(queryRequest.getColumnIndex("level"))
                    ));
        }

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerController.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerController.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.user=userArraList.get(position);

        holder.lbName.setText(userArraList.get(position).getName());
        holder.lbScore.setText(userArraList.get(position).getScore()+"");
        holder.lbLevel.setText(userArraList.get(position).getLevel()+"");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userArraList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView lbName;
        private TextView lbScore;
        private TextView lbLevel;
        private User user;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            lbName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbName);
            lbLevel=itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbLevel2);
            lbScore=itemView.findViewById(R.id.lbScore);

        }


    }
}
```

This images shows how i see the leader board when i execute the app, the first image is how i see one item and the second one is the blank space between both items

[image: When i see one item i cant see the rest]

[image: Separation between 2 items on the recycler]

Comment: In your `RecyclerView`'s item layout change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
edit this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/txtNameOption"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

To:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/txtNameOption"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: Omg i change the recycler in the leader board activity but dont thing about that. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the same problem explained and resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45948056/11388522).

The Relative Layout passed to your Recycler has `android:layout_height="match_parent`, but should have `android:layout_height="wrap_content`, otherwhise every item will be height as much as RecylerView is.

Answer (score 1):

You have to adjust your recyclerview's cell height to wrap content instead of match parent:

VIEW FOR RECYCLER

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/txtNameOption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

match_parent height would scale the cell to the height of the parent view